# drupal Webform select list empty first value

Tags: select, drupal, default-value, drupal-webform

I need for my select lists to have a default option of an empty value, or "Select" with no value.
I don't see any mention of how to do this in the documentation.
// $Id: webform.module,v 1.196.2.47 2010/08/16 17:54:19 quicksketch Exp $

Comment: This question is not really programming related, but about Drupal configuration. If no-one answers here, you may try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @berkes: I've seen you direct people to webmasters.stackexchange.com in a couple of other places. I respectfully disagree -- this is the place to answer drupal related questions. 3000+ plus questions related to drupal have been asked on stackoverflow and a big chunk of them have nothing to do with programming but configuration. All the top drupal answerers hang out on stackoverflow and not on webmasters. The scope of the questions fits stackoverflow. You shouldn't interpret programming literally. Nothing personal, just my opinion. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal

Comment: Well, I friendly point out to the authors of questions that go unanswered that there is an alternative where they might get answers. OTOH, I disagree with your point about configuration. The FAQ states that problems with software usage are not appropriate on SO. It is debatable whether or not using Drupal is software-usage or -development. But for sure it is unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the patch [webform_select_none_0.patch](http://drupal.org/files/issues/webform_select_none_0.patch) as mentioned in http://drupal.org/node/563170. Or if you do not have any experience with patches, you can add the following code to the **_webform_render_select** function in /sites/all/modules/webform/components/select.inc (of course taking into account any disadvantages of manually editing code)

```
if ($component['extra']['aslist'] && !$component['extra']['multiple'] && ($default_value === '' || !$component['mandatory'])) {
    $element['#empty_value'] = '';
}
```

This will add the **- Select -** option to *mandatory* webform select fields when no option is selected

Answer (score 0):

On the webform controls tab (`node/%/edit/components/%`), all you need to do is uncheck the "Mandatory" checkbox under "Advanced Settings".

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module and use form alter to modify the output.  Explained here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1331956#comment-5876808

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can achieve this with an empty entry in your option list:

```
|--Choose one--
val1|Value 1
val2|Value 2
val3|Value 3
```

etcetera.

However, I can't seem to find any sources on this at the moment. Good luck!